# oracle exchange partition with ODI

Tags: oracle12c

I am trying to use exchange partition knowledge module in ODI.

When I create two tables with different column order, exchange partitions is working correctly. But when I change column order with alter table script, exchange partition is giving this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION

this code is giving above error:

```
ALTER TABLE schema1.CALLPARTITIONED EXCHANGE PARTITION call_partition WITH 
TABLE schema2.CALL_TEMP WITHOUT VALIDATION;
```

I do not understand the difference between these two methods. Why does not it work correctly when I change table column order after create?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post the code giving that error

Comment: posted code giving that error.